# Error adding a Patch with a diff file

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I have some trouble adding a patch using a diff file.
I created the diff file using two C sources in this way:

```
$diff gitrans.c.origin gifstrans > giftrans.diff
```

When I try to create a patch using the diff file I obtain this error:

```
$patch -p1 < giftrans.diff
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

Could someone help me please? I can't find a solution.

Comment: If you're stuck with a 'diff' file someone else generated, and it's a "normal" diff (i.e., not "unified" (-u), and not a "context" (-c) diff), then you can still use `patch` with the option `-n` (normal diff). If there is more than one file in the patch, the filenames will have to be manually entered during the patch apply process.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the correct syntax. Use like this:

```
$diff -aNur gitrans.c.origin gifstrans > giftrans.diff
```

Where

```
-a , treats it as text
-N , treats absent files as empty, useful if you want
     just changes of different existing files but not 
     for new files
-u , output as unified. This is need to fix you problem
-r , recursively, useful if you want diff directories
```

I always forget the options, therefore I just remember the word **`aNur`**. It's easy to remember.

Answer (score 2):

You should use unified diff format with the given patch syntax

```
$diff -u gitrans.c.origin gifstrans > giftrans.diff
$patch < giftrans.diff
```

or the default diff format with the following patch syntax

```
$diff gitrans.c.origin gifstrans > giftrans.diff
$patch gitrans.c.origin giftrans.diff
```